# How to print out keys and values of one array based on keys and values of another array?

Tags: php, arrays, loops, multidimensional-array, foreach

I have an array that looks like this.

```
[DETROIT] => Array
(
    [NORTH] => 20.00%
    [SOUTH] => 30.00%
    [WEST] => 25.00%

)

[CHICAGO] => Array
(
    [NORTH] => 59.14%
    [SOUTH] => 12.94%
    [WEST] => 0.00%
    [EAST] => 34.60%
)

 [NEW YORK] => Array
(
    [WEST] => 38.00%
    [EAST] => 49.00%
)

[DALLAS] => Array
(
    [WEST] => 60.57%
)
```

With the help of another user, I got the code to print it out like this table.

```
          DETROIT     CHICAGO   NEW YORK   DALLAS
NORTH     20.00       59.14      N/A       N/A
SOUTH     30.00       12.94      N/A       N/A
WEST      25.00       0.00       38.00     60.57
EAST      N/A         34.60      49.00     N/A
```

This is my code for printing out the following table:

```
echo "<table>";
$heading = "<tr><td>&nbsp;</td>";
$stats_key = array("Stat 1","Stat 2","Stat 3");
$cities = array();
foreach ($stats as $city=>$city_stats){
$cities[] = $city;
$heading .= "<td>" . $city . "</td>";
}
$heading .= "</tr>";
foreach ($stats_key as $key){
$table .= "<tr><td>" . $key . "</td>";
foreach ($cities as $cit){
 $table .= "<td>" . $stats[$cit][$key] . "</td>";
}
$table .= "</tr>";
}

echo $heading;
echo $table;
```

I have another array, with the keys being the people in charge of these locations.

```
[John Doe] => Array
(
    [0] => DETROIT
    [1] => DALLAS

)

[Sara Smith] => Array
(

    [1] => NEW YORK
)

 [Donald Duck] => Array
(
    [0] => CHICAGO
)
```

Now, I just want to print out the same table, but the locations that are under the same person get printed out together, like so:

```
           DETROIT     DALLAS   NEW YORK   CHICAGO
  NORTH     20.00       N/A      N/A       59.14
  SOUTH     30.00       N/A      N/A       12.94
  WEST      25.00       60.57    38.00     0.00
  EAST      N/A         N/A      49.00     34.60
```

Any help would be appreciated, thanks.

Edit:
This is what I've done so far:

```
echo "<table>";
$heading = "<tr><td>&nbsp;</td>";
$stats_key = array("Stat 1","Stat 2","Stat 3");
$cities = array();

foreach($PERSON as $per){
foreach ($stats as $city=>$city_stats){
$cities[] = $city;
$heading .= "<td>" . $city . "</td>";
}
$heading .= "</tr>";
foreach ($stats_key as $key){
$table .= "<tr><td>" . $key . "</td>";
foreach ($cities as $cit){
 $table .= "<td>" . $stats[$cit][$key] . "</td>";
}
$table .= "</tr>";
}

echo $heading;
echo $table;
}
}
```

But that extra foreach loop got me too many duplicates. Also, no two people can be in charge of one place.

Comment: So can you show what you have done to attempt to aggregate these columns together?

Comment: Can more than one person be in charge of a place?

Comment: what kind of duplicates?

Answer (score 0):

The last foreach in your code

```
foreach ($cities as $cit){
    foreach($person_name as $charge){
        if($charge = $cit){
            $table .= "<td>" . $stats[$cit][$key] . "</td>";
            break;
        }else{
            $table .= "<td> N/A </td>";
        }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

As far as I understood, you need to display cities in the same order as they appear in the second array.

Try this:

```
$array1 = array(
    'DETROIT' => array(
        'NORTH' => '20.00%',
        'SOUTH' => '30.00%',
        'WEST' => '25.00%',
    ),
    'CHICAGO' => array(
        'NORTH' => '59.14%',
        'SOUTH' => '12.94%',
        'WEST' => '0.00%',
        'EAST' => '34.60%',
    ),
    'NEW YORK' => array(
        'WEST' => '38.00%',
        'EAST' => '49.00%',
    ),
    'DALLAS' => array(
        'WEST' => '60.57%',
    ),
);
$array2 = array(
    'John Doe' => array(
        'DETROIT',
        'DALLAS',
    ),
    'Sara Smith' => array(
        'NEW YORK',
    ),
    'Donald Duck' => array(
        'CHICAGO',
    ),
);

function get2ndLevel($arr, $bKeys = false) {
    $vals = array();
    array_walk($arr, function($v, $k) use(&$vals, $bKeys){
        $vals = array_merge($vals, $bKeys? array_keys($v) : array_values($v));
    });
    return array_values(array_unique($vals));
}

$dirs = get2ndLevel($array1, true);
$cities = get2ndLevel($array2);
$cities = array_merge($cities,
    array_values(array_diff(array_keys($array1), $cities))
);

$table = "<tr><td>&nbsp;</td>";
foreach ($cities as $city){
    $table .= "<td>" . $city . "</td>";
}
$table .= "</tr>";
foreach ($dirs as $dir){
    $table .= "<tr><td>" . $dir . "</td>";
    foreach ($cities as $city){
        $table .= "<td>" . (isset($array1[$city][$dir])? $array1[$city][$dir] : "N/A") . "</td>";
    }
    $table .= "</tr>";
}

echo "<table>". $table. "</table>";
```

[Demo](http://codepad.viper-7.com/UbP1bN)

Comment: That is what I want to do, but I'm not sure if I follow.

Comment: Your original code cannot output the given table. It has to be fixed.
See my updated answer.